# Selenium Webdriver drag'n'drop from parent to child iframe

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've been looking for any working solution to drag'n'drop for the past 5 days. 
So,

Selenium.WebDriver 2.44.0

WebDriver.ChromeDriver.win32 2.13.0.0

Chrome latest version.

C#, Page object pattern.
Sorry for russian descriptions on screens :)

We have .net cms. It has pages Editor. Editor opens in parent page, page to edit if loaded in iframe from the same domain.

I need to drag'n'drop items (pictures, video, etc) to a concrete containers in iframe.As far as I understood the following is used in CMS: This file contains following files: jQuery 1.11.1 + jQuery UI 1.10.4 + jQuery Migrate 1.2.1 */).

Piece of code: http://screencast.com/t/ArEk54ue

Here is a scenario during drag'n'drop:

1. In parent content I select some element id=someelement. (String  is not active).
2. I click and hold on element, pulling it into iframe.
3. The following code appears in parent page:

4. Child element appear in String from the 1-st step. It's our element.

See screen: http://screencast.com/t/Cio4knwp

5. When I pull element to iframe onmouseover event fires and child string appear in the following string:

http://screencast.com/t/cpj3ihlE959

Containers change their color to green on mouseover.
Container code inside iframe:
http://screencast.com/t/Z6QBD6IYuB

What I've tried to do:

1. Simple webdriver drag'n'drop doesn't work since target element inside iframe.
2. Drag'n'drop by X,Y offset doesn't work too.
3. Drag'n'drop using Actions:

   MoveToElement:

public Actions MoveToElement(IWebElement element)
       {
           var builder = new Actions(Webdriver);
           return builder.MoveToElement(element);
       }

source - picture which I pull

target - container.

WrapperSelenium.MoveToElement(source)
                .ClickAndHold(source)
                .Build()
                .Perform();

WrapperSelenium.SwitchToFrame("WebsiteFrame");

WrapperSelenium.MoveToElement(target)
                .Release(target)
                .Build()
                .Perform();

Doesn't work too.

4.I've tried to use some Javascript hacks, don't remember exactly what  - no success.

5. Now I'm trying ro use jquery-simulate (https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext) - I can click an hold element, containers become active, but I can't release element and find target.

   Please help!

Comment: Watch the below video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egdUfivmm-k" may help you.

Comment: this method doesn't work with iframe

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use AutoIt - developers made to complex code structure